# Error php sql: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

When I tried to run this function I get:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error:** Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in /var/www/html/include/function/token.php:73 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/view.php(14): dirTOperm('/var/www/html/u...') #1 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/html/include/function/token.php on line 73

The function is as follows:

```
function dirTOperm($dir){
    global $mysql_ip, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_database_name,$_SESSION;


    $conn = new mysqli($mysql_ip, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_database_name);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM token-perm WHERE directory = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $dir);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $checktoken = $result->num_rows;
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    if ($checktoken == 0) {
      $permtoken = GenerateRandomString(512);

      $conn = new mysqli($mysql_ip, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_database_name);
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO token-perm (token,directory,date) VALUES ("?","?","?")');
      $stmt->bind_param('sss', $permtoken,$dir,date('d-m-Y H:m'));
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
      $conn->close();
      return $permtoken;
    }else {
      return $row['token'];
    }
  }
```

Connection data is correct and trying to search on google I have not risen to solve, can you help me?

Comment: You need to check the result of `prepare()`, it might return `false`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Using dashes in table names is somewhat ... emm ... gnarly.

Comment: Note: you don't need to use quotes `"` around the `?` the prepared statements will pack the variable for you.

Comment: even without " the problem does not resolve

Comment: I know, this was just a note not a solution. Anyway do `echo $conn->error` after the prepare statement to see the error

Comment: This is the error that comes with the command echo $ conn-> error (
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ stmt' (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/include/function/token.php on line 119)

Comment: it's `$conn` not `$ conn` remove the space . And remember to mention my name so I get notified if you responded to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never use dashes(-) in table names